# How to display data from API inside a bootstrap collapse/modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a school project about API, and I have problems displaying specific data inside a bootstrap collapse.

I have a school project, where I take data about coins from API server and present it. Every coin is presented in a different div and within that div there is a button.  This button is "More Info", and should display more info about that coin, from a link with a specific id, similar to the coin. I managed to present the data from the API server, but couldn't make the button work.
This is the link for the "More Info" button: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/{id}

This is the html:

```
    <body>
    <div class = "header">
        Cryptonite
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div> </br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navigation">
            <div id="buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="home-btn" onClick="selectTab" name="home">Home</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="live-btn" onClick="selectTab" name="live">Live Reports</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="about-btn" onClick="selectTab" name="about">About</button>
            </div> 
            <div class="search">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search through site content"/> <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="src-btn" name="src">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </br>
        <div class="coins">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the script:

```
//This is the function to call the data from the API server
function callCoins() {    
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
            $(".coins").append(`
                <div class="coin">
                    <span>
                        <p id="coin-sym">${data[i].symbol}</p>
                        <p>${data[i].name}</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a${data[i].id}">More Info</button>
                        <div class="collapse" id="a${data[i].id}">example</div>
                    </span>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="b${data[i].id}">
                     <label class="custom-control-label" for="#b${data[i].id}"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </br>
            `)

        }
    }
})
}

//This is the function for 'More Info'
function moreInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/{id}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $(".collapse").append(`
                <div class="moreInfo">
                    <span>
                        <p>${data.image.thumb}</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
            `)
        }
    })
}
```

When I click on "More Info", it should display data from a link with the coin specific id.

Here is a [Demo File](https://jsfiddle.net/guymelech/bh81xfjm/)

Comment: You aren't passing an id to the api in `moreInfo`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not invoking the moreInfo function on click of the button. so your More Info HTML Button has to be like this.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a${data[i].id}"  onClick="moreInfo('${data[i].id}')">More Info</button>
```

and the `moreInfo()` function to be like this

```
function moreInfo(id) {  /* change 1 - added id parameter*/
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+id, /* change 2 - added the id parameter to the api call */
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $(".collapse").append(`
                <div class="moreInfo">
                    <span>
                        <p>${data.image.thumb}</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
            `)
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this helps. And to Make it appear as an image you have add an image tag inside the p tag and bind the image url into the src attribute.

Comment: it works partially. it does create the new div, the problem is that every time i click on 'More Info' , it shows the images from the other ones i previously clicked on. Thank you very much.